# How can I generate a link with two separate inputs using ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, url, parameters

I have two forms on a page, let's call them "Form A" and "Form B". Each form can be used to search for a movie and display the movie's information, so at most, two movies can displayed on the page at a time. Since the forms use ajax, the page doesn't have to reload every time a new Movie A or B is chosen, but a user can't use the URL to link to whatever specific movie combination he or she is on, because ajax doesn't update the url.

I want to supply a link with parameters corresponding to the current movies, which would have to be updated if either Movie A or B is updated. So if Movie A is "Blink" and Movie B is updated to "Crash", the string would be updated to read: `www.website.com/movies?A=Blink&B=Crash`.

If the page only displayed one movie, it would be easy. But here the trick is that when I update Movie B, I have to be able to update the value of `params[:B]` while retaining the value of `params[:A]`, and vice versa. If the current "get link" is `www.website.com/movies?A=Blink&B=Crash` and I update Movie A to "Shrek", then the new "get link" should be `www.website.com/movies?A=Shrek&B=Crash`. And so on.

Anyone have any ideas for how I could do this?

---

Here's the basics of my code (I tried to exclude anything superfluous):

**movies.html.erb**

```
<div id="GetUrl"></div>

<form id="Form A"><!-- points to movies_controller:new_movieA --></form>
<div id="MovieA"></div>

<form id="Form B"><!-- points to movies_controller:new_movieA --></form>
<div id="MovieB"></div>
```

**movies_controller.rb**

```
def new_movieA
  @movieA = Movie.find(params[:movie])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end

#More of the same for movie B.
```

**movieA.js.erb**

```
$("#MovieA").html("j render @movie_a")
$("#GetUrl").html("http://movies?a=&b=<%=@moviea.title%>")
```

**_movie_a.html.erb**

```
<%= @movieA.content%>
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, I want to say that `js.erb` is not the best practice. It better to use `.js` on frontend side.

As I understand the problem is how to get another film name. There are two simple solutions that I see:

1.if you have an element with film name - get it and put in the link:

```
var movieName = $("movieNameElement").text()
$("#GetUrl").html("http://movies?a=" + movieName + "&b=<%=@moviea.title%>")
```

2.get params from old link via regex:

```
var oldLink = $("#GetUrl").text()
var movieName = new RegExp('[\?&]' + paramName + '=([^&#]*)').exec(oldLink)
$("#GetUrl").html("http://movies?a=" + movieName[1] + "&b=<%=@moviea.title%>")
```

hope it helps